# What were the rights and freedoms of Amir Temur's empire citizens?

Tags: social-history, central-asia

[Amir Temur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timur), aka Tamerlane, was a strong personality that managed to build an empire between 1365 and 1405. The trade flourished in many cities along with science.

[Institutes: political and military](https://archive.org/details/dli.venugopal.471/page/n9/mode/2up) that is related to the topic of society regulation, seems to be vague in that regard.

I want to understand what rights and freedoms various middle and lower class people possed in the empire of Amir Termur. It can include the right to travel to Mecca without paying taxes or maybe costs were paid by the government.

Comment: Just added that. Please, confirm that question became improved or more information is needed.

Comment: Re-reading the question, _all_ answers on H:SE are expected to be backed by sources. The literature request is superfluous

Comment: Is your question the one in the title? Then it is best to repeat and explain in the body of the text. For instance, are you asking about written rights and freedoms? (Almost surely there would be none.) Are you asking about more general written laws?